# Why IMultiValueConverter doesn't get updated ObservableCollection as a parameter?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an `ItemsControl` that was set like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding GameObjects}" 
                          AlternationCount="{Binding GameObjects.Count}" 
                          Grid.RowSpan="10"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="10">
```

```
<DataTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.DataContext>
            <vm:MainWindowViewModel/>
        </Grid.DataContext>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex), 
                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        <Image>
            <Image.Source>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource 
                    ObservableCollectionItemByAlternationIndex}">
                    <Binding Path="Textures"/>
                    <Binding Path="GameObjects"/>
                    <Binding Path="(ItemsControl.AlternationIndex)"
                        RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </Image.Source>
        </Image>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

The converter looks like this:

```
public override object Convert(object[] v, Type t, object p, CultureInfo c)
    {
        var value1 = (ObservableCollection<string>)v[0];
        var value2 = (ObservableCollection<GameObject>)v[1];
        var value3 = (int)v[2];

        foreach(var tex in value1)
        {
            if ("/Maelstrom;component//Data/Resources/Textures/" + value2[value3].GetType().Name + ".png" == tex)
            {
                return new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,," + tex));
            }
        }

        return new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,," + value1[0]));
    }
```

The issue here is that when I update `GameObjects`, converter doesn't gets updated version of `GameObjects`, instead of it, `value1` will contain all elements that were inside `GameObjects` when program started. `ItemsControl` updates normally (items that were removed from `GameObjects` also were removed from the UI).

Comment: It is unclear if that DataTemplate is supposed to be used as the ItemTemplate of the ItemsControl. However, it does not make any sense to assign a new MainWindowViewModel instance to the DataContext of each item. Remove the DataContext assignment and set `RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}"` to the first two Bindings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are are confusing `INotifyPropertyChanged` with `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

A multi-binding is only updated if one of the properties in one of the bindings issues an `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event.  In other words, if the *entire collection* underlying `Textures` or `GameObjects` was completely replaced with a brand new instance of `ObservableCollection`

But that's not what happens when you add/remove items to/from an `ObservableCollection`.  In that case, the property that returns that collection object does not change at all;  The very same `ObservableCollection` object remains.  But the collection *itself* raises the `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event.

The only way that WPF can react to this is if some object is monitoring that specific `ObservableCollection` object for `INotifyCollectionChanged`.  And that cannot possibly happen when you use it in a `MultiBinding` because the `ObservableCollection` gets lost in the conversion.  The `MultiBinding` returns one single value and whatever that value is, it's not any object that implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`.

You might want instead to look into the `CompositeCollection` class.  That might be a better approach

Comment: Thank you for answer. At least now I understand why its all heppening